# Weird Cooks distance results using DESeq2

Tags: r, bioinformatics, sequence-analysis

I'm currently trying to assess fold change when comparing two different sample types using DESeq2 package and I'm getting weird Cook's distance values which are causing major problems.

The two different samples have different amounts of replicates (6 replicates vs 5 replicates) which might be the reason for these weird results (since when i remove one sample the results are no longer "weird").

So, the results:

First of all, the condition I'm using is:

```
   name     Type
total_1 t_24
total_2 t_24
total_3 t_24
total_4 t_24
total_5 t_24
nuc_1   n_24
nuc_2   n_24
nuc_3   n_24
nuc_4   n_24
nuc_5   n_24
nuc_6   n_24
```

Since the total is the control, they need to be the first for the LFC to be positive when up-regulated in the test.

Now the code I'm using is

```
df_conditions <- data.frame(
  sample = df_conditions$name,
  condition = df_conditions$Type
)

# The data is only a fraction of the "data_combined" were c(9,10,11,12,13,14) corresponds to the nuclear fraction 
DEA_matrix <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(data_combined[c(9,10,11,12,13,14,23,24,25,26,27)],          
                                     df_conditions, 
                                     ~condition) 

DEA <- DESeq(DEA_matrix)
DEA_results <- results(DEA)
```

When i ran my sample I get around 350 genes with NAs (in both p-value and padj) which, after looking both online and on the manual means that there is a problem with cooks distance value.
After checking these values for the genes using `assays(DEA)[["cooks"]]` i saw that, for example:
For a given gene which has NAs i got these cook's distance values

```
    nuc_1        nuc_2        nuc_3         nuc_4        nuc_5        nuc_6      total_1      total_2        total_3      total_4      total_5 
1.479392e-04 1.548888e-02 1.557630e-04 2.008926e-01 1.012255e-01 2.222557e+01 5.412296e-01 1.156913e+00 9.553727e-01 1.107007e+00 1.146971e+00
```

Which indicates that nuc_6 is clearly the outlier but the normalized reads do not indicate that :

```
nuc_1   nuc_2   nuc_3   nuc_4   nuc_5   nuc_6   total_1 total_2 total_3 total_4 total_5
400      350    400     450      300     400      50     30      30      30     30
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why the cook's value is so weird and indicating an outlier when clearly there isnt one? Could it be the difference in the sample number? I've already tried inverting the order of the condition dataframe (put the nuclear first) but the results remain the same so I don't think its wrongly identifying the nuc_6 as part of the total.

Any ideas?

```r
sessionInfo( )
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_1.0.0               scales_1.2.1                AnnotationDbi_1.60.0        enrichplot_1.18.3          
 [5] GGally_2.1.2                clusterProfiler_4.6.0       preprocessCore_1.60.0       DESeq2_1.38.1              
 [9] SummarizedExperiment_1.28.0 Biobase_2.58.0              MatrixGenerics_1.10.0       matrixStats_0.63.0         
[13] GenomicRanges_1.49.0        GenomeInfoDb_1.34.4         IRanges_2.32.0              S4Vectors_0.36.1           
[17] BiocGenerics_0.44.0         EnhancedVolcano_1.16.0      ggrepel_0.9.2               ggplot2_3.4.0              
[21] gplots_3.1.3                WGCNA_1.72-1                fastcluster_1.2.3           dynamicTreeCut_1.63-1      
[25] readxl_1.4.1               

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] backports_1.4.1        shadowtext_0.1.2       Hmisc_4.7-2            fastmatch_1.1-3        plyr_1.8.8             igraph_1.3.5          
  [7] lazyeval_0.2.2         splines_4.2.2          BiocParallel_1.32.4    digest_0.6.30          htmltools_0.5.4        foreach_1.5.2         
 [13] yulab.utils_0.0.6      GOSemSim_2.24.0        viridis_0.6.2          GO.db_3.16.0           fansi_1.0.3            magrittr_2.0.3        
 [19] checkmate_2.1.0        memoise_2.0.1          cluster_2.1.4          doParallel_1.0.17      Biostrings_2.66.0      annotate_1.76.0       
 [25] graphlayouts_0.8.4     jpeg_0.1-10            colorspace_2.0-3       blob_1.2.3             xfun_0.35              dplyr_1.0.10          
 [31] crayon_1.5.2           RCurl_1.98-1.9         jsonlite_1.8.4         scatterpie_0.1.8       impute_1.72.3          survival_3.4-0        
 [37] iterators_1.0.14       ape_5.6-2              glue_1.6.2             polyclip_1.10-4        gtable_0.3.1           zlibbioc_1.44.0       
 [43] XVector_0.38.0         DelayedArray_0.23.2    DOSE_3.24.2            DBI_1.1.3              Rcpp_1.0.9             viridisLite_0.4.1     
 [49] xtable_1.8-4           htmlTable_2.4.1        gridGraphics_0.5-1     tidytree_0.4.2         foreign_0.8-83         bit_4.0.5             
 [55] Formula_1.2-4          htmlwidgets_1.6.1      httr_1.4.4             fgsea_1.24.0           RColorBrewer_1.1-3     reshape_0.8.9         
 [61] pkgconfig_2.0.3        XML_3.99-0.13          farver_2.1.1           nnet_7.3-18            deldir_1.0-6           locfit_1.5-9.6        
 [67] utf8_1.2.2             ggplotify_0.1.0        tidyselect_1.2.0       rlang_1.0.6            reshape2_1.4.4         munsell_0.5.0         
 [73] cellranger_1.1.0       tools_4.2.2            cachem_1.0.6           downloader_0.4         cli_3.4.1              generics_0.1.3        
 [79] RSQLite_2.2.19         gson_0.0.9             stringr_1.5.0          fastmap_1.1.0          ggtree_3.6.2           knitr_1.42            
 [85] bit64_4.0.5            tidygraph_1.2.2        caTools_1.18.2         purrr_0.3.5            KEGGREST_1.38.0        ggraph_2.1.0          
 [91] nlme_3.1-160           aplot_0.1.9            compiler_4.2.2         rstudioapi_0.14        png_0.1-8              treeio_1.22.0         
 [97] tibble_3.1.8           tweenr_2.0.2           geneplotter_1.76.0     stringi_1.7.8          lattice_0.20-45        Matrix_1.5-1          
[103] vctrs_0.5.1            pillar_1.8.1           lifecycle_1.0.3        data.table_1.14.6      cowplot_1.1.1          bitops_1.0-7          
[109] patchwork_1.1.2        qvalue_2.30.0          R6_2.5.1               latticeExtra_0.6-30    KernSmooth_2.23-20     gridExtra_2.3         
[115] codetools_0.2-18       gtools_3.9.4           MASS_7.3-58.1          assertthat_0.2.1       withr_2.5.0            GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9
[121] parallel_4.2.2         grid_4.2.2             rpart_4.1.19           ggfun_0.0.9            tidyr_1.2.1            HDO.db_0.99.1         
[127] ggforce_0.4.1          base64enc_0.1-3        interp_1.1-3
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the documentation and the original paper of the method, the authors  applied independent filtering setting p-values to NA for genes which do not pass the filter step. That is what the documentation says about it:

*The results function of the DESeq2 package performs independent filtering by default using the mean of normalized counts as a filter statistic. A threshold on the filter statistic is found which optimizes the number of adjusted p values lower than a significance level alpha (we use the standard variable name for significance level, though it is unrelated to the dispersion parameter α
). The theory behind independent filtering is discussed in greater detail below. The adjusted p values for the genes which do not pass the filter threshold are set to NA.*

http://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#independent-filtering-of-results

You can remove the option by setting independentFiltering to FALSE in the results function.

Also, following the documentation:

*The results function automatically flags genes which contain a Cook’s distance above a cutoff for samples which have 3 or more replicates. The p values and adjusted p values for these genes are set to NA. At least 3 replicates are required for flagging, as it is difficult to judge which sample might be an outlier with only 2 replicates. This filtering can be turned off with results(dds, cooksCutoff=FALSE)*.

What you can do here it's to set cooksCutoff to FALSE to see whether your genes are outliers or if they did not pass the independent filteringstep. I bet the latter is more likely to occur.

However, I will give you some good practices learnt from my own use. It is strongly inspired by the workshops I gave in my lab.

Even if DESeq2 is a very powerful tool to assess differential expression between two or more conditions, it is often a bad practice to use it as "black box". I will provide a "ready-to-go" tutorial, to present you, what kind of parameters you can play on, for which purpose.

Before going any further, the tool was designed for balanced or unbalanced design. Except if you suscept some contamination for certain replicate, we can expect stable expression levels for replicates within the same condition. If you do suspect contamination, removing the replicate should be the best thing to do.

Anyways, we assume that that the gene expression for the gene i in the sample j  follows a
$$NB(\mu_i, \alpha_i)$$

Since the data are often overdispersed, one of the main task of DESeq2 is to correctly estimate the overdispersion parameter. To do so, authors provide an empirical bayesian method to "shrink" dispersion estimate to the fit curve. Indeed, using only about 10 replicates to estimate overdispersion is not enough to obtain stable estimates, authors use all the available information from all genes to stabilize estimation. That is what you can see from this:

[image]

You can change the model to fit the red curve, i.e., to adjust your model to your data. It is the first step to do (second actually after checking whether your data are over dispersed) before going any further.

Then, if you have a small number of replicates by condition (which is your case here), I strongly recommend to use shrinkage methods to obtain your LFCs. One major advantage I see to use it, it's to correct your estimates when variance is high or little information is available for one gene, making the LFC comparable across a large range of designs. Again, you have different methods leading to different results. Here just an example of "unadjusted" LFCs versus "shrink" LFCs when normal distribution is used as prior.

[image]

Regarding your question on Cook's distance, one thing you could do, if you suspect leverage for some gene, is simply plotting the Cook's distance for each gene and see what you can conclude. Anyways, you can find whether your gene is considered as an outlier and the Cook's distance using mcols(DEA_matrix). However, I do not expect that outliers play a key role in your case since all steps in DESeq2 was designed to reduce low count impacts on variance estimation.

Finally, I cannot strongly recommend you enough to read the original paper. It is very clear and present all the core concepts with a biological perspective. DOI:10.1186/s13059-014-0550-8

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the detailed response. I've checked the filtering step using the function "metadata(DEA_results)$filterThreshold" and no values were filtered meaning that every value passed the filtering step. I've also tried randomly adding one sample to the total fraction (by making a copy of one of the other samples) and removing randomly one of the nuclear samples and every time the problem solved itself so I'm further inclined that the cause of the problem is de discrepancy between replicate number

Comment: Did you check whether your values are considered as outliers ? You should have the information using mcols.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations that might help, based on the 11 count values you provide.

First, it seems strange to have so many replicates with the exact same number of counts (3 with exactly 400, 4 with exactly 30) if the underlying distribution is supposed to be negative binomial (as I understand that DESeq2 assumes). I don't use DESeq2, so maybe there's something going on in the way it does the normalization.

Second, the 11 data values you show indicate a slight problem with Cook's distance in a standard linear model. Try the following:

```
countVals <- c(400,350,400,450,300,400,50,30,30,30,30)
labVals <- c(rep("n",6),rep("t",5))
plot(lm(countVals~factor(labVals)))
```

One sample in the last plot of standardized residuals versus leverage shows a Cook's distance greater than 0.5. The sample in question is the one with 300 counts, however, and I think that is too low to be flagged by DESeq. And these estimates are probably affected by the value grouping noted above. If you repeat this with:

```
plot(lm(countVals[c(1:5,7:11)]~factor(labVals[c(1:5,7:11)])))
```

similar to your removing one sample from analysis, no samples exceed a Cook's distance of 0.5.

Third, the default cutoff for the Cook's distance with DESeq depends on the number of samples. Reducing the number of samples will make the cutoff larger and reduce the number of outliers that are flagged.

Fourth, the [vignette](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#outlier) says about the Cook's distance cutoff:

> The default is to use the 99% quantile of the F(p,m-p) distribution (with p the number of parameters including the intercept and m number of samples).

A 99% quantile for a cutoff means that you can have 1% false positives. As the Cook's distance is calculated "for every gene and for every sample," having 350 genes flagged when you are presumably evaluating on the order of 20,000 genes in 11 samples might just represent those false positives.

My sense is that the use of Cook's distance in DESeq is to help identify particular *samples* that show a problem. Try manual inspection of the samples with respect to PCA and boxplots of Cook's distance values. See the section in the vignette: "Note on many outliers."